# Parsing excel and rebuild logic in python

Tags: python, excel

I want to transfer excel logic into a python program.

My goal would be to automatically parse an excel file and end up with a python file that can recalculate the results of the excel file and has where I would be able to change parameter to recalculate results etc.

Can someone give me guidance of how to best achieve this?

- available packages?
- previous work on this
- etc.

I don't really know where to start and would be thankful for ideas / guidance.

One idea I am thinking of is storing cell information in nodes where each node contains information such as value of the excel cell and children / parents of the cells (i.e. if excel cell is referencing to other cells). One excel file is then essentially a tree / graph with nodes.

Thanks